# Format value from Request.InputStream as valid JSON in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

Hi I get bellow string from `Request.InputStream`

```
searchbtn=&__RequestVerificationToken=Cj00sURmj5hhazrlcx72-ahnRwOFhZzMOO5hdMH8epMUFTkicNYlKy9Fs3nZdq_Whzr3I57zZqsncWybsNrQ47Sg4vGQB6GbqRPrL3D0o3Q1
&ClientID=274&CompanyName=&PerformedDate=&X-Requested-With=XMLHt
tpRequest
```

is there any trick to format this string as valid JSON string?

Comment: How are you passing it back to the controller? Is it via AJAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing you can do is simply let the modelbinder handle it by having your action accept the data as a class instance. For example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PerformedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
public ActionResult Foo(MyViewModel model)
```

There's not really any reason you should have to access the request `InputStream` directly. If you then need that as JSON for some reason, you can simply do something like:

```
var json = Json.Encode(model);
```

Short of that, you'll simply need to parse it manually and create an object out of it. For example:

```
var data = inputString
    .Split(new[] { '&' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => s.Split(new[] { '=' }))
    .ToDictionary(d => d[0], d => d[1]);
```

You can then get it into JSON via: `Json.Encode(data)`.

Comment: I have tried 2nd option ,but get an error **A local or parameter named 'd' cannot be declared**

string qs = "searchbtn=&__RequestVerificationToken=Cj00sURmj5hhazrlcx72-ahnRwOFhZzMOO5hdMH8epMUFTkicNYlKy9Fs3nZdq_Whzr3I57zZqsncWybsNrQ47Sg4vGQB6GbqRPrL3D0o3Q1";
            qs += "& ClientID=274&CompanyName=&PerformedDate=&X - Requested - With = XMLHttpRequest";


            var data = qs.Split(new[] { '&' }, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(s => qs.Split(new[] { '=' })).ToDictionary(d => d[0], d => d[1]);

Comment: The problem is `Select(s => qs`. This should be `Select(s => s`.

Comment: Using this same problem

 var data = qs
                    .Split(new[] { '&' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(s => s.Split(new[] { '=' }))
                    .ToDictionary(d => d[0], d => d[1]);

Comment: I change d to o (o => o[0], o => o[1]); and its working . dont know why?
and add bellow code to get JSON string.
 string j = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data,Formatting.Indented);

Thankx for help.

Answer (score 0):

Chris Pratt has the best answer, but if you insist on doing what you ask, you can do it like this:

```
var nameValueCollection = 
System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.InputStream);
var dictionary = nameValueCollection.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => 
nameValueCollection[k]);
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary);
```

It does require that you don't have duplicate keys in the request string.